# How to open emacs GUI

Tags: emacs

There are [many guides online](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/install-emacs-editor-on-linux/) to install emacs. They are all the same (like the one I have linked).

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
emacs testfile        (SUPPOSED to runs the GUI)
emacs -nw testile     (-nw runs emacs in the terminal)
```

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04 and installed emacs. When I run `emacs testfile` it just runs emacs inside the terminal window. I've searched all over online and `man emacs` but I don't see any information on forcing emacs to use the GUI.

Does anyone know if there is a secret setting or command line option to toggle the default to use GUI vs. terminal mode?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [askubuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 was released almost 4 years ago. You might want to consider a newer release.

Comment: @sds The explicit question posed in the post is about emacs, not Ubuntu. Ubuntu was used as a specific instance for reproducibility.

Comment: @sds Sorry missed your other comment, just waiting on 18.04 to release soon, bud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ubuntu package `emacs` is a meta package, which in 14.04 depends on `emacs24`.

`emacs24` is a virtual package provided by `emacs24-lucid` and `emacs24-nox`.

From my experience with Ubuntu, `emacs-lucid` will generally be selected by default, but if you already had `emacs-nox` installed for some reason, the dependency will already be satisfied, so your `apt-get install emacs` will not install the graphical version of Emacs.

Also, even if you have the graphical version of emacs installed, it requires the DISPLAY environment variable to be set, to direct it where to display the initial frame.  If you are not running your command shell within an X window, or you have used sudo, or some other command that creates a different environment within the shell session, DISPLAY may not be set (you can check with `echo $DISPLAY`).

Answer (score 0):

You can install `emacs-gtk` to have additional GUI support:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-gtk
```